# Flask+Vue Flask session are not persistant because of SameSite problem in chrome

Tags: vue.js, cookies, cross-domain, samesite

I'm trying to use Flask + Vue build using the SPA style mentioned in the article:
https://testdriven.io/blog/combine-flask-vue/

When using chrome, Flask sessions are not persistent
google dev tools is raising a SameSite problem:
[image]

I tried to fix it according to the information I found in stack overflow:
settings:

```
from flask import Flask, make_response
from flask import session
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_session import Session

from SodukoUtils import init_board_options, find_next_move
from data.sudopy import Sudoku

app = Flask(__name__)
SESSION_TYPE = 'filesystem'
app.secret_key = b'abjdslgjl'
app.config.from_object(__name__)
CORS(app, supports_credentials=True)
Session(app)
app.config.update(
    SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE=True,
    SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY=True,
    SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE='None',
)
```

However, the problem stil remains when I use the chrome browser.
When I use the Mozila browser, the flask sessions work fine.

In Vue I use fetch to send http requests by setting mode to 'cors' and credentials to 'include'
For example:

```
fetch(url, {
        mode: 'cors',
        credentials: 'include',
      })
```

**github repository [link](https://github.com/idannik/Flask_Sudoku)**

packages information:
[image]

Comment: any repo for your test code?

Comment: @TarunLalwani I added to the details https://github.com/idannik/Flask_Sudoku

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to solve this because I can't install your dependencies or run your application.

I think you're doing this correctly. I suggest setting the `app.config` values *before* initializing the CORS and Sessions packages. Additionally, in the response handler you could manually set the headers to mark `"SameSite=None"`. The code for this is below.

```py
response.set_cookie('username', 'flask', secure=True, httponly=True, samesite='Lax')
```

See the documentation [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/security/#security-cookie)

Comment: I wrote the package information above. I tried your suggestion, it didn't work

Comment: OK, the first thing you need to figure out is how to set *any* headers with flask. This is not a Vue issue. Do a Flask tutorial for creating a server with custom headers.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to set samesite=None on Chrome for a flask app, i wrote a workaround on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62992831/python-session-samesite-none-not-being-set/64015801#64015801) by using the `SecureCookieSessisonInterface` class from `flask.sessions` and adding the `after_request` decorator on the response using the `response.headers.add()`.